# Call Spring Service and pass arguments to constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this simple Spring Service:

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    @Autowired
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    private Terminals terminal;    

    @Autowired
    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(Terminals terminal) {  
        this.terminal = terminal;
    }
}
```

I want to call the service from here:

```
@Service
public class FilterProcessing {

    @Autowired
    private BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilter; 

    public PaymentResponse someMetohd(Terminals terminal,
              PaymentTransaction message, HttpServletRequest request) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {

        switch(.......) {
            case ".......":
                // send here the args via Contructor
                binCountryCheckFilter.validateBinCountryCheckFilter(terminal);                  
                break;
            case ".........":           
                .........
                break;

                break;                                          
            }           
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I'm not aware how to send the object `terminal` via the `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl` constructor.
Is there some solution for this?

Comment: According to your code I can only guess that terminal is an object which you receive in runtime, while binCountryCheckFilter constructed on all beans initialization phase.

Comment: *Make up your mind:* Is `terminal` a global value supplied once by the Spring Framework at initialization time, or is it a per-request value supplied by the method caller at runtime? --- Since `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl` is a **singleton**, you shouldn't store per-request values in *fields*.

Comment: Trying to understand your requirement. Why can't you use terminal setter instead of constructor argument?

Comment: You should not autowire beans, that change during runtime. It will cause concurrency issues.

Comment: @IvanLymar Unless the bean has `@Scope("request")`, aka `@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)`

Comment: @Pavel - yes I received it from configuration. Data and attributes of Terminal are not important.

Comment: @Andreas terminal is a value for every request.

Comment: @PeterPenzov So that answers your question. The singleton bean `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl` cannot have the per-request value `terminal` as a field, i.e. as a parameter on the constructor. The `terminal` value must be passed as a method parameter, as already indicated by the method call you're showing.